# Affecting the parent only

Tags: css

Lets get straight to the point, I have created this example to better get my point across:

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/urryfof5/4/)

**HTML:**
Table 1

```
<table class="testClass">
    <tr>
        <td>Inner table
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                    <td>Testing testing</td>
                    <td>Bye</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />Table 2
<table class="testClass">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Left</td>
        <td>Middle</td>
        <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
/* Relative CSS */
 .testClass tr:last-child td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 15px;
}
.testClass tr:last-child td:nth-child(2) {
    width: auto;
}
.testClass tr:last-child td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 15px;
}
```

So we have 2 tables, both with the same class. `Table 1` has a table within it where as `Table 2` does not.

The problem I'm finding with this is using the CSS I have created I am unable to stop the styles for `.testClass` from affected the child table (Inner table). I was thinking that `:not()` could be used but am unable to find a solution using it tho I feel this shouldn't be that hard.

Is it possible to only affect the parent within the styles from the parent getting to the child table?

Note: The CSS can only be changed not the HTML. CSS3 can be used!

I hope this made some sense, if I need to make it clearer please leave a comment.

Comment: Why not use something like `.testClass > tr...` to style only the direct children? Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/urryfof5/2/).

Comment: @Harry This should be `.testClass > tr, .testClass > tbody > tr` since the table body is inserted automatically by most modern browsers.

Comment: @feeela: Yes, good point.

Comment: @Harry This stops table 2 from getting the CSS. It should end up with table 1's inner table not getting the style at all so the widths should not be set (I have added a background to make it clear where the style is).

Comment: @Ruddy: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/urryfof5/8/) closer to what you want? The problem with the `width` was because you had `tr:last-child td:nth-child(n)` which points to a `td` which is directly/indirectly (via another parent) under the `tr`.

Comment: @Harry Ah ha! I think that is it, so I needed to add in `tbody`! As I did try that but with out `tbody` in the CSS. Excellent work to you and feeela. Could you put that as an answer please.

Comment: @Ruddy: Just now realized that this version is pretty much the same as Suresh's answer mate. So, it wouldn't be nice to add a near duplicate version. I will leave a comment in his answer.

Comment: @Harry Thing is that I already tried that, the answer was I needed to add `tbody`. But yeah can do if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the first level child and apply it.

```
   .testClass > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(1) {
      width: 15px;
   }
  .testClass > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(2) {
     width: auto;
   }
   .testClass > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(3) {
      width: 15px;
   }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urryfof5/9/)

Comment: This stops table 2 from getting the style [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urryfof5/5/)

Comment: Mate, please refer to feeela's comment in the question, the `tbody` is also needed because most browsers add it by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could add style-declarations like

```
table table { border: none; }
```

to override styles from the parent `table`-declaration. This way, no nested tables will have the border. The same thing applies for the `td`s.

Another solution would be:

```
table:not(.testClass) {
    border: 0px none; 
}
```

which removes the border for all tables that do *not* have the `testClass` applied. I tested and saw this work (in another version of the below Fiddle).

Here's a **Fiddle with your code** with two additional declarations, removing the borders for the inner table:
http://jsfiddle.net/erlingormar/bk6m4w5d/#base

Answer (score 0):

maybe this way : http://jsfiddle.net/urryfof5/7/

Basically you call the last-child table from the body and add > so it won't affect nested tables inside:

```
body > table:last-child (and follow it with your css)
```

Comment: Please include the code in your answer and explain what you have done. Oh know, this is using body, sorry I wasn't looking. There are loads of tables on the page this wouldn't work.